# Present a message to user before requesting a permission

Tags: java, android, permissions

I'm using the permission-dispatcher library for permission handling and it's working great. One thing I didn't find is the ability to present a message to the user **prior** to the permission request explaining why I'm requesting this permission (I'm familiar with the `@OnShowRationale` annotation but it'll kick in only if the user denied the permission at first)

Comment: You will have to create your own custom dialog and trigger the permission dialog after the user interacts with your custom dialog.

Comment: I hoped to avoid it and use onpy the library...